# Cloudflare's ipfs Gateway vs. hosting your own ipfs gateway

Tags: ipfs

I'm trying to impelement an ipfs gateway. I'm on cloudflare and saw that they already have their gateway you can CNAME to.

What are the pros/cons of hosting your own Gateway vs. using Cloudflare's

Answer (score 2):

If you host your own gateway, you have complete control over what content is stored/served on it. You could also be helping serve the wider network by not relying on Cloudflare as a SPoF.

**Pros of hosting your own gateway:**

- Control over what's served/stored on the gateway (could pin content you want served faster on the node, blacklist content you don't want)
- Contribute to the wider network of gateways, no longer relying on solely CloudFlare as a SPoF
- Control over the gateway makes it easier to serve your website as the intended domain (don't have to rely on CNAME)

**Cons of hosting your own gateway:**

- Possible moral/legal responsibility to block bad content
- Costs could be more than a regular node if the gateway is public